# c++ passing object which using abstract class type gives error: is not a member of GeneralDriverInterface

Tags: c++, interface, pure-virtual

i have simple General interface that looks like this :

```
Class GeneralDriverInterface 
{
public:
virtual void Init() = 0;
};
```

Then i have class which Uses one of the sub class which Initializes the GeneralDriverInterface interface .

```
 class DriverTest : public GeneralDriverInterface 
    {
        public: 
        DriverTest();
        virtual void Init();
        bool TestMe();

    }

    void DriverTest::Init()
    { 
       //init driver stuff 
    }

    bool DriverTest::TestMe()
    { 
       //test driver stuff 
    }
```

Now to use this DriverTest class it get Initialized in Class via function

```
// in the Processing.h header there is :

    GeneralDriverInterface* m_GeneralDriverInterface;
    void Processing::InitDriver(GeneralDriverInterface* _GeneralDriverInterface)
    {
       m_GeneralDriverInterface = _GeneralDriverInterface;
       m_GeneralDriverInterface->Init();
       m_GeneralDriverInterface->TestMe();  // The problematic call !! where it failed in compilation 
    }
```

It gets its Driver class via constructor from class GeneralFactory like this :

```
GeneralFactory::SetProcessingDriver()
{
    GeneralDriverInterface pGeneralDriverInterface = new DriverTest()
    m_pProcessing->InitDriver(pGeneralDriverInterface );
}
```

ok i tried to use the abstract interface to be general as possible , but im getting :

```
 error C2039: 'TestMe' : is not a member of 'GeneralDriverInterface'
1>        g:\project\GeneralDriverInterface.h(6) : see declaration of 'GeneralDriverInterface'
```

my question is do i need to include all the functions im going to use in the implemented class's ?

Comment: Do you expect a base class to magically add all the members of all its derived classes to its own interface?

Comment: Yes you need all the functions you use via the interface in the interface.

Answer (score 0):

> my question is do i need to include all the functions im going to use in the implemented class's ?

Yes, you need to include all of the functions you need to *use via the interface pointer or reference*.

Any other functions implemented in classes deriving the interface don't need to be declared there.

You can still use `dynamic_cast<>` or `static_cast<>` to get a pointer or reference of the implementing class.

Comment: well this is what i want to have very general methods in the interface but 
the sub class which implement the interface will have public methods of its own

Comment: @user63898 They can have public functions of their own, you just can't access these via the interface unless you're doing a cast.

Answer (score 0):

`m_GeneralDriverInterface` is of type `GeneralDriverInterface`.

The class `GeneralDriverInterface` doesn't have a method `TestMe()`.

> do i need to include all the functions im going to use in the
>   implemented class's ?

Yes, yes you do.

How is the compiler supposed to know what kind of of method it should call?

Comment: Mr Bates , i want to use the interfaces as general type , but every class that implement the interface will have its own functions also

Comment: @user63898 You either have to specify the other methods pure virtual in your base class as well (or virtual and only implement them in their respective classes) or if you're sure you're dealing with an object of a certain type you can `dynamic_cast` the pointer and then call the appropriate method.